# Can't exec "bin" : Bad file descriptor (Perl)

Tags: perl, exec

I'm trying to fix a problem for a day and after many unfructuous searches i'm here !

I'm trying to use the binary convert from the ImageMagick suite on a Perl script to crop an picture.

When i try this simple code :

```
use Shell qw(convert);

convert("-crop", "50%x50%", $Src, "new_image.png");
```

On a single file that works perfect.

But when i try to implement it on the project i'm working on (i'm on internship ,fixing features now), the message "Can't exec convert : Bad file descriptor" appears !

I checked the path of $Src, try to remplace by hard code, set PATH, nothing change.

BUT

if i try a simple:

```
 convert(-h);
```

That Works perfect !
I supposed something in the previous code may be interfering but not sure.

Ps : The project is launched from a php server hosted in local, donno if it change something but if never !

Thanks a lot for reading and thank too for answering !

---EDIT---
Actual code as asked

```
Use Shell qw(convert);

.
.
.

sub checkSubScreen
{
#Parameters init
my ($this, $Scr0, $Scr1) = @_;

    convert("-crop", "50%x50%", $Scr0, "tmp/scr0_crp.png");
    convert("-crop", "50%x50%", $Scr1, "tmp/scr1_crp.png");
....
```

I can't show you the entire code it's really too big but just ask and i'll try to show !

Comment: We'll need to see the actual problematic code in order to help you.

Comment: Is there a reason the title says `Can't exec "bin"`, but you report the error as `Can't exec convert`?

Comment: Yeah to keep the title a little more generic, but that doesn't change a thing in the problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message comes from [`Shell`](http://search.cpan.org/~ferreira/Shell-0.72/Shell.pm). I don't know what anyone thinks they are gaining by using `Shell` instead of the more traditional `system`/`qx`/pipe open/`IPC::Open3` toolkit, and in particular I don't see what you are gaining by using `Shell`.

Try the more traditional system call

```
@args = ("50%x50%", $Src, "new_image.png");
system("convert", @args) and warn "convert @args: exit code was $?";
```

and see if you get a more traditional error message.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally i decided to use the PerlMagick Api it works, i think my problem was due to the environment and probably very specific.

Thks for answers !